# Overlapping background image through different elements

Tags: html, css

How can I get the main background image (the topography) to start from the very top all the way to the very bottom.

The golden "bars/elements" and blue "bars/elements" functionality is that they are like an accordion. So by clicking them, the element below it becomes visible or vice versa. So the the topography would be overlapping the golden and blue bars and continuing to the next section be it either another bar or the element that is visible. The topography image should never break throughout the entire page.

[image: website demonstration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what do you mean by Topography but if you want an image to start from top and end at the bottom of the page, you can use the following method :

CSS:

```
.background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <span class="background"><img src="xxxxx" /></span>
  <!-- your content goes here -->
</body>
```

What this will do is, create a div that will be equal to the height of the body tag and will be always aligned to the top left corner of the page. The image may get skewed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What your suggesting is to an have absolute element on top of all my other elements?

Comment: What I'am referring to by "main background image (the topography)" is the background image in the attached image on my post that has a topography pattern on it.

Comment: yep, giving it position absolute will make sure that it is always on top of your elements. Giving it left and top 0 will make sure that it is always in the left top corner of the page. And giving it 100% height width will make sure that it will cover the whole page from top to bottom.

Comment: I have written on my post that the elements need to be clickable. Which will not be the case anymore if I have an absolute element covering them.

Comment: Sir, it will work if you give this property to your background:-   pointer-events: none; This will disable the click on the background and will allow user to click on accordion.

Comment: any luck? do let me know if it didnt work. Also it will help if you can share codepen.